# Something wrong with my html form and pure css?

Tags: html, css

I have the following html:

```
<head>
  <link href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.3.0/base-min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/item" class="pure-form pure-form-stacked" method="POST">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="item">Name of item</label>
            <input id="item" name="item" type="text" />
            <label for="desc">Description</label>
            <input id="desc" name="desc" type="text" />
            <input type="submit" value="Add" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
```

This does not render as the example in http://purecss.io/forms/ shows (Stacked form), but more like the inline form (and not very nice at that). Is there something wrong with my html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not including the pure-form css.

Add

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.3.0/pure-min.css">
```

To your head.

http://jsfiddle.net/jaap/tFAWe/

(I added the button classes to the button and a legend node to the fieldset).

Comment: Agreed, also could you add the `<legend>` tags to this just to help him some more.

Comment: Ok, legend is added :), within a fieldset <legend> is required.

Comment: Ahh thanks! Not sure if this was quite clear from the pure documentation :)